# Laravel app works locally, but not remotely on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm trying to get my laravel app working on Heroku. Though it works fine when I serve locally via "php artisan serve", it doesn't work when I deploy to Heroku and query the Heroku site. When I try querying the Heroku site, I get a message in the browser saying, "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I have no idea how to debug this, as I am new to Laravel and Heroku. I noticed that Heroku has a log page for my app, but it doesn't show any crash logs.

Comment: please check your `.env` and enable `APP_ENV=dev` for your deployment file. Then you should get a proper error Msg. Did you set up a new `APP_KEY` ? If not, try using `php artisan generate:key` on your server cli.

Answer (score 1):

First, just make sure that .env file have the right credentials,
2nd, check the errors log file in app/storage/logs/laravel.log